# Restricting the text to be entered in a cell with Custom Formula (Data Validation)

Tags: vba, excel

I've a string in a Cell which contains a date in `YYMMDD` format in it's first 6 characters. I want to restrict the user to enter only the value which is greater than or equal to current date.

`170712` should be allowed as it's greater than or equal to current date `170712`.

With VBA, the following formula is working fine:

```
CLng(Left(Range("H10").Value, 6)) >= CLng(Right(Year(Date), 2) & Format(Now, "MMDD"))
```

The same formula is not working when put it custom formula under data validation !

How should I put this in Data Validation Custom Formula Field in excel so I can restrict user the way I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

The code would be like this.

```
If Range("h10") >= Format(Date, "yymmdd") Then
```

If the cell of validation is b1 cell,  the validation formula is bellow.

```
=B1>=TEXT(TODAY(),"yymmdd")
```

Comment: I have to use the same formula which I mentioned above. It's about extracting first 6 digits and then comparing with current date. Could you please check how to put that formula in Data validation field?

Comment: @sbk:  modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to put today() in a cell, and do the data validation for Date with refrence to >= to that cell. Inside data validation.

Comment: I have to use the same formula which I mentioned above. It's about extracting first 6 digits and then comparing with current date. Could you please check how to put that formula in Data validation field?

Answer (score 0):

Try this custom formula in data validation.

```
=(DATEVALUE(TEXT(B1,"mm/dd/yy"))>=DATEVALUE(TEXT($A$1,"mm/dd/yy")))
```

The above formula is to apply data validation in `Column B` when the date `170712` is in cell `A1`

[image]

Comment: `CLng(Left(Range("H10").Value, 6)) >= CLng(Right(Year(Date), 2) & Format(Now, "MMDD"))` If I wanted to use this code, What modification I need to make to get it worked in Custom Formula?

Comment: @sbk  You want to compare the date entered always with today's date?

Comment: first I need to extract first 6 characters and then I have to compare it with the current date.

Comment: first 6? what is the full length string then? how lengthier it is?

Comment: The string is a combination of date and two more parameters that are alpha numeric. The string may be of length 20.

Comment: `=(DATEVALUE(TEXT(LEFT(H10,6),"mm/dd/yy"))>=DATEVALUE(TEXT(TODAY(),"mm/dd/yy")))`  try this